# Is it "burn money on" or "burn money over"?

Tags: grammar

I am not sure if both are the same. They sound synonymous, but I think I might be wrong.

For example:

> He burned all his savings on 10 escorts accompanying him to a 5 star
>   restaurant.
>
> He burned all his savings over 10 escorts accompanying him to a 5 star
>   restaurant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely *on*.  I would use *over* for something he did because some event drove him a little bit crazy: “He blew his savings over the breakup with his fiancee” (spending it on frivolities to console himself).